# Why is plenv install-cpanm installing to the wrong location?

Tags: perl, cpanm, plenv

Something wacky happened with my plenv setup and I haven't gotten my head around it.

```
plenv install-cpanm
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  297k  100  297k    0     0  1571k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1567k
!
! Can't write to /Library/Perl/5.18 and /usr/local/bin: Installing modules to /Users/olaf/perl5
! To turn off this warning, you have to do one of the following:
!   - run me as a root or with --sudo option (to install to /Library/Perl/5.18 and /usr/local/bin)
!   - Configure local::lib in your existing shell to set PERL_MM_OPT etc.
!   - Install local::lib by running the following commands
!
!         cpanm --local-lib=~/perl5 local::lib && eval $(perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5/ -Mlocal::lib)
!
App::cpanminus is up to date. (1.7042)

$ plenv which cpanm
plenv: cpanm: command not found

$ find /Users/olaf | grep bin/cpanm
/Users/olaf/.cpanm/work/1482416411.97013/App-cpanminus-1.7042/bin/cpanm
/Users/olaf/.cpanm/work/1482416863.23085/App-cpanminus-1.7042/bin/cpanm
/Users/olaf/perl5/bin/cpanm

$ find /Users/olaf/.plenv | grep cpanm
/Users/olaf/.plenv/libexec/plenv-install-cpanm
/Users/olaf/.plenv/plenv.d/rehash/rehash_cpanm.bash
```

I would expect `cpanm` to get installed somewhere inside of `~/.plenv`, but that's just not happening.  I'm guessing something in my dot files/shell setup/`$ENV` is messed up?

This is what my `$ENV` looks like:

```
env | grep PLENV
PLENV_SHELL=bash
```

Also, the beginning of my `PATH` is:

`PATH=/Users/olaf/.plenv/shims:/Users/olaf/.plenv/bin`

Comment: Can you post the environment variables you have set for plenv? Should be something like: `PLENV_PATH='export PATH="$HOME/.plenv/bin:$PATH"'
PLENV_INIT='eval "$(plenv init -)"`

Comment: @interduo sorry, holidays got in the way.  I've updated my question to include the relevant `%ENV`.

Comment: And I've now been given a solution, so I posted it as my own answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this sorted with some help from Tatsuhiko Miyagawa.  It turns out that I had switched to the system Perl via `plenv` and had expected it to handle module installs in the same way that it works for Perls which `plenv` installs for you.  The solution was just to choose a version of Perl which I had installed earlier via plenv (`plenv local 5.24.0`) and then to `plenv install-cpanm`.  Tatsuhiko Miyagawa also pointed out that I'll need to `install-cpanm` for each version of Perl that I have installed.